# What is the correct way to put parameters in web.config in MVC - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I have create this mail send form with MVC 4 in ASP.NET. Now I whant to put (use) parameters for smpt, username, password and port number in my Web.config. I have try this solution:

In Web.config:

```
<add key="smptserver" value="smptABC" />
<add key="username" value="usernameABC" />
<add key="password" value="passwordABC"/>
<add key="portNum" value="123"/>
```

In my Controller.cs I have this:

```
using System.Configuration;

...

string host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smptserver"];
string user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
string pass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
string port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["portNum"];

using (var client = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = host,
    Port = port,
    EnableSsl = true,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass),
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
})
{ ...
```

I have also found this solution (all same, but only this is changed):

```
string host = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["smptserver"];
string user = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["username"];
string pass = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["password"];
string port = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["portNum"];

[other is same]
```

What are the diffrences between "ConfigurationManager" and "ConfigurationSettings"? 
Is this a proper way to set parameters with Web.config?

Thanks for explanation.

Comment: The second solution is deprecated, use the first one. And it's just a matter of retrieving data, not setting it.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting passwords in your web.config file. See http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure for how to move them out.

Comment: tnx for answer :) @RickAnd - MSFT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `ConfigurationSettings` exposes deprecated (marked as "obsolete") functionality.  (Your code *should* be generating warning messages at compile time to indicate this.  If it's not, turn warnings back on.)

[`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is preferred.